# Toolbar moved down after updating vuetify 0.15 -> 0.17

Tags: vuetify.js

After updating i got [the problem here.](https://codepen.io/Claus1/pen/zpyqVX?&editors=101) It is codepen link.

Tried to add new props to the toolbar  but everything is wrong. How to solve?

```
i = 1
```

Comment: Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. If you use **v-navigation-drawer** add **absolute**.

Full Code :

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" temporary absolute>
```